# Behavior at 24:00:00 in moment().isValid()

Tags: momentjs

I am validating the date and time with `moment().isValid()`, but the date and time validation at 24:00:00 does not work as expected.

```
console.log(moment('2020-07-02 24:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',true).isValid());
```

I want the result of the above code to be `false`, but the actual behavior is `true`.
How can I implement the above phenomenon to get the expected result?

We also conducted tests on parts that seemed to be related, but the behavior at 60 minutes, 60 seconds, etc. was as expected.

```
// 24:00:00
console.log(moment('2020-07-02 24:00:00').isValid());                            //true
console.log(moment('2020-07-02 24:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').isValid());      //true
console.log(moment('2020-07-02 24:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',true).isValid()); //true (Unexpected)
console.log(moment('2020-07-02 24:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss',true).isValid()); //false
console.log(moment('2020-07-02 24:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD kk:mm:ss',true).isValid()); //true

// other
console.log(moment('2020-07-02 24:00:01','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',true).isValid()); //false
console.log(moment('2020-07-02 24:01:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',true).isValid()); //false
console.log(moment('2020-07-02 23:58:60','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',true).isValid()); //false
console.log(moment('2020-07-02 23:59:60','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',true).isValid()); //false
console.log(moment('2020-07-02 22:60:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',true).isValid()); //false
console.log(moment('2020-07-02 23:60:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',true).isValid()); //false
console.log(moment('2020-07-02 23:60:60','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',true).isValid()); //false
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems caused by following issue:

- [Is there any workaround for handle datetime format as "24:00" #1174](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1174#issuecomment-25950746) - moment/moment

> In ISO 8601, Midnight is a special case and can be referred to as both "00:00" and "24:00" (Midnight day after and Midnight today so to speak). While it should not technically "bubble", it is perfectly valid.

---

As a supplement, [current spec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times) does not seem to permit it:

> Midnight is a special case and may be referred to as either "00:00" or "24:00", **except in ISO 8601-1:2019 where "24:00" is no longer permitted**.